# .jar file won't load resources in properly

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I made a simple little java game that uses many .png files. I exported my game as a .jar file using VSCode. I try to load up my .jar file and the menu screen works fine but when I click play I get an error indicating my pauseOverlay is not being loaded properly

Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1356)

This is weird because everything else seems to work fine. Also, when I run my code in my IDE it all works fine.
The specific line in question that is not loading properly is line 43 in the PauseOverlay class.

To be honest, I am very lost and don't know where to start to fix this issue so that my program can properly run as a .jar file. Here is the code on github: https://github.com/stefancohn/DuckWorld

Comment: Address your resources as `/res/foo...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource names are case sensitive. The resource is called `res/pauseButtons.png` with a `p`, but you try to load it as `res/PauseButtons.png` with a `P`.

Comment: To expand a bit: When you are running your application in the IDE, the resources are loaded from a directory, which means, java asks the OS to open `PauseButtons.png` and assuming it's a case-insensitive file system (which is bad, but default behaviour on windows), that still works. When you pack it into a jar, the resources are loaded from the jar, which means java uses its own jar-reading capabilities to open it. Which __is__ case sensitive. Hence why it works in IDE but fails as a jar. The fix is, as RobSpoor explained, to ensure you don't typo the name (wrong case is, effectively, a typo).